# Invalid Cast from UserControl to custom control

Tags: c#, user-controls, casting

I have several controls that all inherit from `UserControl`, and I have a `MergeSort` method that runs on `UserControl` types (to save me from writing out 6 different methods), but when I cast back to my custom controls after the sorting, it throws an error, what am I doing wrong? The mergesort method requires the `Left` property, which each custom control uses, so is there any other way I can do this?

MergeSort method looks like:

```
public UserControl[] MergeSort(UserControl[] array)
```

Cast looks like:

```
(CustomControl[])MergeSort(customControlArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to cast each of them manually:

```
CustomControl[] customControlArray;
...
UserControl[] sortedControls = MergeSort(customControlArray);
CustomControl[] sortedCustomControls = Array.ConvertAll<UserControl, CustomControl>(sortedControls, delegate(UserControl control)
{
    return (CustomControl)control;
});
```

If you have .NET 3.5+ at your disposal you can use much "cooler" syntax. :)

Edit: the cooler syntax is:

```
UserControl[] sortedControls = customControlArray.ToList().ConvertAll(c => (CustomControl)c).ToArray();
```

:-)

Comment: This worked, combined with using a base class rather than usercontrol

Comment: Cheers @Chi see my edit for the syntax using .NET 3.5 new features. :)

Answer (score 2):

(I deleted my previous answer because I think it was actually incorrect.)

It sounds like you need an abstraction between your controls and `UserControl` which represents common functionality.  There are two main ways to accomplish this, and whichever one you use is a matter of personal coding preferences, how you plan to extend these further, how you organize your code in the project, etc...

1. Inherit from a base class.  Basically, create a `MyCustomControl` (or whatever you want to name it) class which implements the common functionality between your custom controls.  This would inherit from `UserControl` and your controls would inherit from this.  Then your method would expect/return an array of this base class.
2. Implement an interface.  You could create an `ICustomControl` (or whatever you want to name it) interface which represents the common functionality between your custom controls.  Then your controls would inherit from `UserControl` as well as implement `ICustomControl`.  Then your method would expect/return an array of this interface type.

I personally prefer the interface approach.  Inheritance tends to be overused in a lot of people's object oriented code, and really shouldn't be.  An interface better represents an abstraction (or code contract) as a type (as opposed to a class).  But that's a much bigger discussion debate for another time, I suppose :)

Comment: Thanks for that, David, I will try the interface approach